# Azure subscription type handling

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I am currently in a pickle with how to handle in my application a unique scenario which is to offer a specific subscription type that will last only say 3 months and then after that time switch users that subscribe will no longer be able to register for this subscription. Lets say that I am a store that has 2 for 1 offer which will only last for a holiday and afterwards the offer will end. How can I emulate this with Azure marketplace libraries? I know from the following link that you can generate while registering different subscription types, which is useful and we might end up doing it this way, but I would like to know if what I mentioned above is possible and how can I go about and do that?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_introtowazmarketplace_topic6

> Note:
>   Take special consideration at the Submit New Offering form. The information you provide will be used to publish your application (such as Contact Information, Company Name and Company Description). In particular, the Offering Type indicates how your application will be consumed by the Marketplace users.
>
> There are available three offering types:
>
> 1.Commercial application: the application can be purchased through the Marketplace.
>
> 2.Listing-only application: the application is not part of Marketplace offerings, but will be listed in the Applications Catalog.
>
> 3.Data: to register a data set through the Marketplace.
>
> Also, you will specify your application subscriptions and its price. Windows Azure > Marketplace only supports monthly subscriptions. You can choose to add multiple monthly subscriptions. In order to differentiate each offering, please assign a Global Unique Identifier (GUID), for example:
>
> 1.Enterprise Subscription: free (B40878F0-2100-4754-A6C1-50141E6ADC0F)
>
> 2.Business Subscription: free (E52E4425-09E6-4F0B-9764-4FDB0D814526)
>
> 3.Personal Subscription: free (79D8743E-9025-4749-8179-AE516C85FE3E)
>
> You can generate your own GUID using the GUID Generator tool included with the Visual Studio.
>
> If you want to further describe the differences between each subscription type, you can do so in the Features section of the form.